# Access to the same web-page by two different users

Tags: javascript, web, web-applications, multiplayer

I would like to create a simple online web-application (online chess). Each piece is represented as a png pic and has script, which allows a user to move it around with a mouse (via JavaScript mouse events). Now I would like to add multiplayer, so that two different users can see the very same board and immidiately see "updates" of the possition, conducted by each other.
So the idea is that I would like to make another user see changes is style settings (possitioning) of certain elements of the web-page, conducted by a script (which can be used by both players). How can I do that?

I came across some ideas of using .json files, but I suppose that when I use json file this means that each player can see its own "version" of web-page, but gets come data about opponent from json file. However, I would like to avoid it and make users see updates as they are on the same page.
Does it have to do something with sockets and sessions?

Comment: Use websockets for that. Node.js and socket.io is a good starting point.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.